# Java Username Password Array replace with asterix

Tags: java, arrays, string-formatting

So I am writing a program for school that handles usernames and passwords. Its supposed to take prompt for user names and passwords for 3 users. Then display the username and asterisk for the length of the password. I have pretty much everything I need including how to print the asterisk for the length of the password on the same line:

```
//int asterix =password[x].length();
 * for (int y=0; y<asterix ;y++){
 *                  System.out.print("*");
 *              }
 */
```

My issue is I need to format the output like this:

```
USER ID                 PASSWORD

howdyDoodie              ***********
batMan                   ************
barneyRubble             ************
```

So far my code looks like this:

```
  public class test{

    /**
     * 
     * @param args
     */





    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] user = new String[3];
        String[] password = new String[3];

        // Prompt for Username and Password and loop 3 times adding to next value in array
        for(int x=0; x<=2;x++){

        user[x] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Username: ");
        password[x] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Password: ");
        // Test number of loops
        //System.out.println(x);

        }

        //Field Names Print

        System.out.printf("\n%s\t%10s","Username","Password");

        for(int x=0; x<=2;x++){
            System.out.printf("\n%s\t%15s",user[x],password[x]);

        }

     System.exit(0);

    }
    /*
     * //int asterix =password[x].length();
     * for (int y=0; y<asterix ;y++){
     *                  System.out.print("*");
     *              }
     */

} // End of Class
```

I can't figure out how to get the asterisk to print out and use the formatting.

Comment: Try [JPasswordField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html). :)

Comment: BTW this is Asterix: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterix  The * is called asterisk: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterisk

Comment: Guess i've been spelling it wrong for a while. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a nested loop. Move the for loop printing the `asterisk (*)` inside the for loop printing username and password for all users.

Your loop should look like this. It is not tested, but you can work it around to get desired output.

```
System.out.printf("%-20s\t%-10s","Username","Password");

for(int x=0; x<=2;x++) {

     System.out.printf("%-20s\t",user[x]);  // Just print user here

     int asterix =password[x].length();
     for (int y=0; y<asterix ;y++){  // For the length of password 
         System.out.print("*");      // Print *
     }
     System.out.println();   // Print newline to move to the next line
}
```

`%-20s\t` means `username` takes 20 spaces, left-aligned, and add a tab after it.